# Determine byte offset of GetElementPtr

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Here is a simple C program:

```
struct S {char c; short arr[16]; char dummy2;};

extern struct S A[20];
extern short* p;

int main() {
    p = &A[10].arr[6];
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the LLVM IR:

```
%struct.S = type { i8, [16 x i16], i8 }

@A = external global [20 x %struct.S]
@p = external global i16*

; Function Attrs: nounwind
define i32 @main() #0 {
entry:
  store i16* getelementptr inbounds ([20 x %struct.S]* @A, i64 0, i64 10, i32 1, i64 6), i16** @p, align 8, !tbaa !1
  ret i32 0
}
```

How can I calculate the byte offset that is being added to `@A` by the [getelementptr](http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html)?

I can loop through and print out the GEP easily enough:

```
  auto& P = *GEP.getPointerOperand();
  Out << "GEP(";
  GEP.getType()->print(Out); // return type
  Out << ", ";
  P.printAsOperand(Out); // base
  for (auto i=0U; i<GEP.getNumIndices(); i++) {
    Out << ", ";
    GEP.getOperand(i+1)->printAsOperand(Out); // index i
  }
  Out << ")\n";
```

This prints:

```
 GEP(i16*, [20 x %struct.S]* @A, i64 0, i64 10, i32 1, i64 6)
```

Assuming *all* the indices are constant integer, how can you determine the byte offset relative to the base pointer?

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: I'm also trying to find the answer, llvm always give you the most complicated way and doc , it is really hard to find any answer by myself in net

Answer (score 1):

Can you use ptrtoint instructions and subtract them?